# DNS Zone has no address records (A or AAAA)

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, dns-zone, reverse-dns, dns-hosting

Whenever I run systemctl start named.service I get the error:
`zone example.com/IN NS 'linserver-1.myco.example.com.example.com' has no address records (A or AAAA)` Now the confusing thing for me is that even though this failed, I'm still able to ping my server with a client using `ping hostname` even though the DNS service isn't running. I also want to note that `dig, nslookup, and host` commands aren't working.

`nslookup linserver-1` returns `DNS request timed out. Timeout was 2 seconds. Server: UnKnown, Address: 10.150.34.101`

myco.example.db file:

```
@   IN SOA linserver-1.myco.example.com example.com myco.example.com (
        20002001 ; serial
        12h ; refresh
        15m ; update retry
        6w  ; exp
        3h  ; min
        )
@   IN NS linserver-1.myco.example.com.

ns1 IN A 10.150.34.101

linserver-2.myco.example.com    IN A 10.150.34.202
```

forward lookup zone file:

```
$TTL 2d ;

@   IN SOA linserver-1.myco.example.com example.myco.example.com. (
        20002001 ; serial
        12h ; refresh
        15m ; update retry
        6w  ; exp
        3h  ; min
        )
    IN NS linserver-1.myco.example.com
linserver-1     IN A 10.150.34.101
winclient   IN A 10.150.33.20
winserv     IN A 10.150.33.4
linclient   IN A 10.150.33.12
winclient-2 IN A 10.150.34.85
```

Reverse lookup Network 33:

```
$TTL 2d ;
$ORIGIN 33.150.10.IN-ADDR.ARPA.

@   IN SOA linserver-1.myco.example.com example.myco.example.com. (
        20002001 ; serial
        12h ; refresh
        15m ; update retry
        6w  ; exp
        3h  ; min
        )
    IN NS linserver-1.myco.example.com.
    IN NS linserver-2.myco.example.com.
4   IN PTR WinServ.myco.example.com.
12  IN PTR linclient.myco.example.com.
20  IN PTR winclient.myco.example.com.
```

Reverse lookup Network 34:

```
$TTL 2d ;
$ORIGIN 34.150.10.IN-ADDR.ARPA.

@   IN SOA linserver-1.myco.example.com example.myco.example.com. (
        20002001 ; serial
        12h ; refresh
        15m ; update retry
        6w  ; exp
        3h  ; min
        )
    IN NS linserver-1.myco.example.com.
    IN NS linserver-2.myco.example.com.
85  IN PTR winclient-2.myco.example.com.
```

Comment: `IN NS linserver-1.myco.example.com` You are missing the trailing dot there, hence the error message about "linserver-1.myco.example.com.example.com", note how the zone is repeated. In DNS configurations, names without trailing dots are relative to the zone they appear in (or their $ORIGIN pragma for bind)

Answer (score 0):

When I make my Bind server, I used this [link](https://catalin.works/blog/bind9-dns-setup-local-domain-names/#configuring-bind-9)! . Works fine to me.